# Ошибка asyncApi/generator

Tags: api, документация, dockerfile

После выхода версии v1.10.0 при сборке спецификации начались ошибки

> Error: Input is not a corrent AsyncAPI document so it cannot be
> processed. at Generator.generateFromString
> (/usr/local/share/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/@asyncapi/generator/lib/generator.js:264:19)
> at async
> /usr/local/share/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/@asyncapi/generator/cli.js:157:

Есть подозрение, что поменялся config и теперь генерация не проходит из-за новых правил
Можно как-то в docker указать предыдущую версию asyncApi/generator ? Обычный способ asyncApi/generator:1.9.18 не помогает, не находит в registry